# Why is my colorbar not scaling properly?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, legending

I am adding a colorbar to a Plot3d graphic which shades a surface based on some other function of x and y. When I run `BarLegend[{"LightTemperatureMap",{-4,4}}]` I get this output, as expected:
[image]

However, when I run the full plotting script, the color scale is weirdly squished so that the extremes are just solid red and blue

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[0.25+kx^2+ky^2],-Sqrt[0.25+kx^2+ky^2]},{kx,-2,2},{ky,-2,2},
    BoxRatios->{1,1,1},
    ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z},
      Which[z>0,ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][Rescale[0.5/(x^2+y^2+0.25)^(3/2),{-1,1}]],
        z<0,ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][Rescale[-0.5/(x^2+y^2+0.25)^(3/2),{-1,1}]],
        z==0,ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][0.5]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling->False,
    PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"LightTemperatureMap",{-4,4}}],
    Lighting->Automatic
]
```

[image]

Can someone give me an indication of why the colorbar is behaving differently inside the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

funcs = 
  {Sqrt[1/4 + kx^2 + ky^2], -Sqrt[1/4 + kx^2 + ky^2]};

min = Min[MinValue[{#, -2 <= kx <= 2, -2 <= ky <= 2}, 
  {kx, ky}] & /@ funcs]

(* -(Sqrt[33]/2) *)

max = Max[MaxValue[{#, -2 <= kx <= 2, -2 <= ky <= 2}, 
  {kx, ky}] & /@ funcs]

(* Sqrt[33]/2 *)
```

The correct range is

```
BarLegend[{"LightTemperatureMap", {min, max}}]
```

[image]